# How to copy Production Database to Local Database in Grails

Tags: database, grails

I am working on a **Grails** appplication, In this I have to copy all production server database to local database first. I am having **DataSource.groovy** as follows :

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
username = "xxxx"
password = "xxxx"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {

            url = "jdbc:mysql://xxxx"
            username = "xxxx"
            password = "xxxx"           
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            //dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://xxxx"

        }
    }

    production {
    dataSource {
        url = "jdbc:mysql://xxxx_production"
        username = "xxxx"
        password = "xxxx%"
    }
}

staging {
        dataSource {
           url = "jdbc:mysql://xxxx"_staging"
            username = "xxxx"
            password = "xxxx%"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any command in Grails for copy **production environment** database to **local** or **staging environment** database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tools for your current production database to create and apply dumps. Database management is **not a grails job**.

Answer (score 0):

We create sql dumps or backups of the production database, and then you just restore it locally.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same right now, I am running production database backup files(SQL files), which are in db folder of my app, for restore production database locally, but is there any command in Grails, which automatically fetch latest database from production server by fetching settings from DataSource.groovy and save it locally. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about such a feature, but I wouldn't keep my hopes up, there will be a lot of isssues when trying to achieve something like that. To name just a few, your DB sever could be in a dmz for instance and you are not necesarrily going to have access to it. The database might be very big and the command would execute forever, security is going to be an issue too. But I would be curious to see if there is such a feature how they deal with these issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grails Database Migration Plugin.

For further details refer http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html